# Haskell - Cannot understand this type mismatch error

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following code (`yyyy` and `mm` defined to be type `Int`):

```
partOne = truncate  ((fromIntegral yyyy + fromIntegral mm/100) * 1.25 + 0.97)
```

which on being loaded into GHCi gives me an error:

```
No instance for (Integral Float) arising from a use of ‘truncate’
```

However if I directly use the following line in GHCi, it works fine:

```
truncate  ((fromIntegral 2000 + fromIntegral 04/100) * 1.25 + 0.97)
```

There seems to be some problem related to the type `Int`, however I am not able to figure out how.

Also, actually I don't exactly understand what `(Integral Float)` means here.

---

For completeness's sake, the definition of the whole function is included here in case the error is caused by the whole thing instead of that single statement:

```
dowNumber :: Mnemonic -> PhonePad -> Date -> Float
dowNumber mn p (yyyy, mm, dd) = (partOne + partTwo) / 7 where
  partOne = (truncate  ((fromIntegral yyyy + (fromIntegral mm)/100) * 1.25 + 0.97))
  partTwo = fromIntegral ((monthToPhone mn p mm) + dd)
```

`Mnemonic` is just `String` and `PhonePad` is `[(Char, Int)]`. `Date` is `(Int, Int, Int)`.

Comment: Note: StackOverflow's markdown variant doesn't know fenced code blocks, you need to use indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `truncate` has type `(RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`, which means that its polymorphic result needs to fulfil the `Integral` constraint. However, `dowNumber`'s type indicates that `(partOne + partTwo) / 7` is a `Float`. Therefore, `partOne` and `partTwo` *also* need to be `Float`s.

That would be possible if a `Float` was some kind of integral type. But it isn't. But to get a float from an `Integral`, all that's missing is another `fromIntegral`, either at `partOne`:

```
partOne = fromIntegral $ truncate $ …
```

or before you try to divide:

```
dowNumber … = fromIntegral (partOne + partTwo) / 7 where 
   …
```

### How can I fix errors like this easier?

Annotate the types. In this specific case, GHC complained about `truncate`, and therefore about `partOne`. Lets simplify your example for a minute:

```
number :: Float
number = (a + b) / 2 where
  a = truncate $ fromIntegral 5 / 2 
  b = fromIntegral $ 12
```

This creates the same error as your previous program:

```
SO.hs:3:7:
    No instance for (Integral Float) arising from a use of ‘truncate’
    In the expression: truncate
    In the expression: truncate $ fromIntegral 5 / 2
    In an equation for ‘a’: a = truncate $ fromIntegral 5 / 2
```

So, the equation for `a` isn't correct? Lets fix the types of both `a` and `b`:

```
number :: Float
number = (a + b) / 2 where
  a, b :: Int
  a = truncate $ fromIntegral 5 / 2 
  b = fromIntegral $ 12
```

And now it gets clear:

```
SO.hs:2:11:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’ with actual type ‘Int’
    In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘a’
    In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(a + b)’

SO.hs:2:15:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’ with actual type ‘Int’
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘b’
    In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(a + b)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks. So the `(Integral Float)` thing actually refers to `(Part1 / Part2)`? Then isn't the error message actually a bit misleading though. It seems to be saying it was the arguments of `truncate` which caused the issue, while in fact it was the result of it.